# How to allow a number between 0-12 and also have additional pattern aside it

Tags: html, regex

I am trying to figure out a pattern for html and I can't get it to work...

As the result I am looking for something lower than this number: "12.50"

```
<input type='text' class='form-control' name='wrap' id='wrap' placeholder='0.00' pattern='^([1-9]|1[012]+[.]+[0-5]+[0])$' required>
```

I am expecting the first number to be a number between 0-12, after that the "." and after that a number between 0-5 and at the end just the 0.

It works if I only have the 0-12 regex, but when I add the pattern for the period and the rest, it brakes and is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your grouping and use of quantifiers are not correct. Besides, `^` and `$` are redundant in HTML5 `pattern` regex as these patterns are enclosed with `^(?:`  and `)$` automatically upon compiling.

You may use a more precise pattern like

```
pattern='(?:[1-9]|1[012])\.[0-5]0'
```

It will get compiled as `/^(?:(?:[1-9]|1[012])\.[0-5]0)$/` (or with `u` modifier in Firefix and Chrome) and it will match:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:` - start of a [non-capturing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-what-does-do) outer group

  - `(?:[1-9]|1[012])` - a non-capturing group matching numbers from 1 t to 12
  - `\.` - a dot
  - `[0-5]0` - a digit from 0 to 5 and then a zero
- `)$` - end of outer grouping and end of string.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6eGZbl/1) and [Regulex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(%3F%3A(%3F%3A%5B1-9%5D%7C1%5B012%5D)%5C.%5B0-5%5D0)%24):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Ok I got it working, I didn't know that the "|" means OR so I had to tweak my code a little bit.

```
  <input type='text' class='form-control' name='wrap' id='wrap' placeholder='0.00' pattern='^([0-9][.][0-5][0]|1[012][.][0-5][0])$' required>
```

so I had before ^([1-9]|1[012]+[.]+[0-5]+[0])$

If I split it up I get:

[1-9]

AND

1[012]+[.]+[0-5]+[0]

What I actually needed was to add the +[.]+[0-5]+[0] to both patterns